# Realm Android merge two queries

Tags: android, realm

I have a query, for my custom object which I form like this:

```
Path path = paths.get(i);
RealmList<RealmInt> ids = path.getPlaces();
query = realm.where(Place.class);
if(ids.size()==0){

} else {
    int j = 0;
    for (RealmInt id:ids){
        if(j++>0){
             query = query.or();
        }
        query = query.equalTo("id",id.getVal());
    }
}
```

It's from some post at StackOverflow. Now, I want to add .contains to that query but it does not seem to work, it returns items like .contains is not there. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, the key was to use beginGroup() and endGroup()